# How come sql is slower straight after the DB has been created?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-performance

I am doing some performance testing and have found that SQL seems to be performing much slower on a brand new db than on one which has been around a little while, and I would like to know why this is, and how I can prime my DB a bit better after create so that my performance tests are more accurate.

To show my point I have a test app [here](https://gist.github.com/2317397) which does the following:

1. Create database and test table
2. Inserts some rows
3. Truncates the table
4. inserts more rows

2 takes around 1.5x as long as 4

Comment: Caching could explain selects but I'm not sure it explains inserts being slower?

Comment: How do you create your database? do you let the file autogrow?

Comment: @inu thanks that was the issue, post it as an answer and ill mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Inu's note on auto-grow and it looks like this is why the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the database not being in RAM.  Just because the database is created doesn't mean that it's loaded in RAM.  It's likely that SQL Server only does that when the database is in use and probably even releases them if not in use for a period of time.  Similar to caching.

After creating the database try selecting count(*) from the tables just to make sure everything is in ram.  I would then expect 2 and 4 to behave in approximately the same time frame.

Ahh just saw the comment on the auto growth.  That could explain a lot as well as truncating the table will leave that space available so that the server does not have to allocate new pages.  --Good comment lnu.

**Edit** try setting your data and log file to 500 mb before testing to make sure file growth isn't an issue.  Something similar to.

```
CREATE DATABASE [TestDB] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\data\TestDB.mdf' , SIZE = 512000KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\data\TestDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 512000KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: Adding a count (*) to my sample doesnt make any difference to the results, i still get around a 1.5x difference 1376ms vs 915ms

Comment: Try the data an log size set to 500 to avoid any growth issues.

Comment: I assume by upvote that worked for you?  It did come in response to Inu's commment so he should post answer and get some credit.